# Reorganizing mobile divs into desktop, while it remains responsive and elements are not displayed sometimes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

Is it possible to reorganize the divs from mobile view to desktop the way it is in the image below? I tried using grid, but the result wasn't satisfying, because the right elements' height was streched. Also it would be hard to handle a situation by grid, when some divs can be invisible, not displayed at all, because user didn't provide that type of content. Any idea? Thanks!

[reorganazing divs from mobile to desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gros2.jpg)

One possible but bad solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "a d"
    "c d"
    "c e"
    "f e";
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.red, .blue {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: auto;
}

.a {grid-area: a}
.b {grid-area: b}
.c {grid-area: c}
.d {grid-area: d}
.e {grid-area: e}
.f {grid-area: f}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a red">A</div>
  <div class="b blue">B</div>
  <div class="c red">C</div>
  <div class="d blue">D</div>
  <div class="e blue">E</div>
  <div class="f red">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my post with a snippet. As you can see, the gap between the divs are not correct with this grid solution. Also if I remove one div, it breaks the whole thing.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS (flex or grid) given your current structure.

Comment: So, the best solution is to make both the mobile and desktop version, and hide one of them at the right time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't particularly like it (I don't like relying on `grid-auto-flow: dense`, for accessibility reasons: the visual order doesn't resemble the DOM order, so assistive technologies see the content differently), there is a way with CSS grid:

```css
/* CSS custom properties for easier and more convenient
   theming and maintenance: */
:root {
  --black: hsl(0 0 0);
  --blue: hsl(197 71% 73%);
  --blueColumn: 2;
  --columns: 1fr 3fr;
  --red: hsl(0 100% 50%);
  --white: hsl(0 100% 100%);
}


/* a simple CSS reset to remove default margins and padding,
   and have elements sized using the border-box method, which
   includes border-width and padding in the declared size: */
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  /* using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* assigning a gap between adjacent elements within the grid: */
  gap: 0.5em;
  /* to have the grid arrange the content in such a way that
     empty space is minimised within the grid: */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  /* setting the number of columns, and sizes, to the value
     held in the --columns var (declared on the :root): */
  grid-template-columns: var(--columns);
  /* this was my best guess, adjust to taste: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 3em);
  /* equivelent to 'width' in English language sites; the
     inline-axis being left-to-right; here we set the
     preferred size to 60vw, but the element will maintain
     a minimum size of 20em and a maximum size of 1200px: */
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 60vw, 1200px);
  /* in English language sites the block-axis is top-to-bottom,
     this declaration assigns a margin to the element on that
     block-axis: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* sets a margin on the inline-axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  /* adjust to taste, this is simply to center the contents
     of the various <div> elements: */
  display: grid;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 1em;
  place-content: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: var(--red);
  /* placing the .red elements on grid-column 1: */
  grid-column: 1;
  /* using the grid-row to have .red elements span
     over two grid-rows: */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.blue {
  background-color: var(--blue);
  /* places the .blue elements into the value held
     in the --blueColumn custom property: */
  grid-column: var(--blueColumn);
  /* assigns the .blue elements to have a grid-row
     span of the value of the --rowSpan property
     (if declared), otherwise of 1; these properties
     are declared in the HTML in this example: */
  grid-row: span var(--rowSpan, 1);
}


/* when the screen is less than 500px wide (unfortunately
   Firefox doesn't yet support logical properties in
   @media queries): */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* we redeclare some of the properties: */
   :root {
    --blueColumn: auto;
    --columns: 1fr;
  }
  .blue,
  .red {
    /* and here we set the grid-row to span 1 row: */
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a red">A</div>
  <div class="b blue">B</div>
  <div class="c red">C</div>
  <div class="d blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">D</div>
  <div class="e blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">E</div>
  <div class="f red">F</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n86md2fj/).

And, to show why `grid-auto-flow: dense` was required, first without that property being declared:

```css
/* CSS custom properties for easier and more convenient
   theming and maintenance: */

:root {
  --black: hsl(0 0 0);
  --blue: hsl(197 71% 73%);
  --blueColumn: 2;
  --columns: 1fr 3fr;
  --red: hsl(0 100% 50%);
  --white: hsl(0 100% 100%);
}


/* a simple CSS reset to remove default margins and padding,
   and have elements sized using the border-box method, which
   includes border-width and padding in the declared size: */

*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  /* using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* assigning a gap between adjacent elements within the grid: */
  gap: 0.5em;
  /* setting the number of columns, and sizes, to the value
     held in the --columns var (declared on the :root): */
  grid-template-columns: var(--columns);
  /* this was my best guess, adjust to taste: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 3em);
  /* equivelent to 'width' in English language sites; the
     inline-axis being left-to-right; here we set the
     preferred size to 60vw, but the element will maintain
     a minimum size of 20em and a maximum size of 1200px: */
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 60vw, 1200px);
  /* in English language sites the block-axis is top-to-bottom,
     this declaration assigns a margin to the element on that
     block-axis: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* sets a margin on the inline-axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.wrapper>div {
  /* adjust to taste, this is simply to center the contents
     of the various <div> elements: */
  display: grid;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 1em;
  place-content: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: var(--red);
  /* placing the .red elements on grid-column 1: */
  grid-column: 1;
  /* using the grid-row to have .red elements span
     over two grid-rows: */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.blue {
  background-color: var(--blue);
  /* places the .blue elements into the value held
     in the --blueColumn custom property: */
  grid-column: var(--blueColumn);
  /* assigns the .blue elements to have a grid-row
     span of the value of the --rowSpan property
     (if declared), otherwise of 1; these properties
     are declared in the HTML in this example: */
  grid-row: span var(--rowSpan, 1);
}


/* when the screen is less than 500px wide (unfortunately
   Firefox doesn't yet support logical properties in
   @media queries): */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* we redeclare some of the properties: */
   :root {
    --blueColumn: auto;
    --columns: 1fr;
  }
  .blue,
  .red {
    /* and here we set the grid-row to span 1 row: */
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a red">A</div>
  <div class="b blue">B</div>
  <div class="c red">C</div>
  <div class="d blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">D</div>
  <div class="e blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">E</div>
  <div class="f red">F</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n86md2fj/1/).

The above shows obvious gaps that `grid-auto-flow: dense` filled with its layout algorithm in the desktop display, though the mobile (`max-width: 500px`) display works perfectly well.

Alternatively, we could instead use `grid-auto-flow: column`:

```css
/* CSS custom properties for easier and more convenient
   theming and maintenance: */
:root {
  --black: hsl(0 0 0);
  --blue: hsl(197 71% 73%);
  --blueColumn: 2;
  --columns: 1fr 3fr;
  --red: hsl(0 100% 50%);
  --white: hsl(0 100% 100%);
}

/* a simple CSS reset to remove default margins and padding,
   and have elements sized using the border-box method, which
   includes border-width and padding in the declared size: */
*, ::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  /* using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* assigning a gap between adjacent elements within the grid: */
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  /* setting the number of columns, and sizes, to the value
     held in the --columns var (declared on the :root): */
  grid-template-columns: var(--columns);
  /* this was my best guess, adjust to taste: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 3em);
  /* equivelent to 'width' in English language sites; the
     inline-axis being left-to-right; here we set the
     preferred size to 60vw, but the element will maintain
     a minimum size of 20em and a maximum size of 1200px: */
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 60vw, 1200px);
  /* in English language sites the block-axis is top-to-bottom,
     this declaration assigns a margin to the element on that
     block-axis: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* sets a margin on the inline-axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  /* adjust to taste, this is simply to center the contents
     of the various <div> elements: */
  display: grid;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 1em;
  place-content: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: var(--red);
  /* placing the .red elements on grid-column 1: */
  grid-column: 1;
  /* using the grid-row to have .red elements span
     over two grid-rows: */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.blue {
  background-color: var(--blue);
  /* places the .blue elements into the value held
     in the --blueColumn custom property: */
  grid-column: var(--blueColumn);
  /* assigns the .blue elements to have a grid-row
     span of the value of the --rowSpan property
     (if declared), otherwise of 1; these properties
     are declared in the HTML in this example: */
  grid-row: span var(--rowSpan, 1);
}

/* when the screen is less than 500px wide (unfortunately
   Firefox doesn't yet support logical properties in
   @media queries): */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  /* we redeclare some of the properties: */
  :root {
    --blueColumn: auto;
    --columns: 1fr;
  }
  .blue,
  .red {
    /* and here we set the grid-row to span 1 row: */
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a red">A</div>
  <div class="b blue">B</div>
  <div class="c red">C</div>
  <div class="d blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">D</div>
  <div class="e blue" style="--rowSpan: 4">E</div>
  <div class="f red">F</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n86md2fj/2/).

This looks fine on desktop but, on mobile, the rows are clearly being shown out of order.

References:

- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/).
- [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to CSS Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)," CSS-Tricks.
- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," CSS-Tricks.
- "[Basic concepts of grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)," Mozilla Developer Network.
- "[Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)," Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: The height of each div is not responsive. Let's say I insert a huge "Lorem ipsum" text to replace "B". It'd be the same height and the text wouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Web: then I don't think it's possible at all, sadly. It feels like it *should* be, but I can't see a way to have it work with that constraint.